# Creating a dictionary of a particular row in a csv file

Tags: python, dictionary, key

Suppose my file is somewhat in this way:

```
['720',
'717',
'"Diagnostic"',
'487',
'"{""status"": ""active""',
'""division_type"": ""Organisation""}"']
```

I need to select **487** as the key in a new dictionary and the words following 487 as it is. Basically a dictionary within a new dictionary. I have tried out the following code:

```
for row in line:
    key = row[3]
    if key in d:
         pass
    d[key]=row[21:]
print(d)
```

I chose 3 because 487 is the 3rd index and i chose 21 because in the csv file the following line is in the row number 21.

I am a newbie to programming. Please help me out.
The error in the message is: index is out of range

Comment: I can't share the data. And no it's not JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say without further data the following approach is more or less experimental but might be a good starting point. You could look for the key in question (`487` in your case) and for consecutive curly braces:

```
import re
from ast import literal_eval

file = """
['720',
'717',
'"Diagnostic"',
'487',
'"{""status"": ""active""',
'""division_type"": ""Organisation""}"']"""

rx = re.compile(r'(?P<key>487)[^{}]+(?P<content>\{[^{}]+\})')

for m in rx.finditer(file):
    content = re.sub(r"""'?"+'?""", '"', m.group('content'))
    d = {m.group('key'): literal_eval(content)}
    print(d)
```

This yields

```
{'487': {'status': 'active', 'division_type': 'Organisation'}}
```

Or, more general, as a function:

```
def make_dict(string, key):
    rx = re.compile(r'(?P<key>' + key + ')[^{}]+(?P<content>\{[^{}]+\})')

    for m in rx.finditer(string):
        content = re.sub(r"""'?"+'?""", '"', m.group('content'))
        yield {m.group('key'): literal_eval(content)}

for d in make_dict(file, '487'):
    print(d)
```

In general, fix the input format of the file!